# Using preg_replace to remove iframe videos not working

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I am trying to separate the images and videos (vimeo) from the text content of my wordpress project post using `preg_replace`. Only the images are being filtered out but not the iframe videos.

```
<div class="post_text">
    <?php
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/<iframe[^>]+>.*?<\/iframe>/', '', $content);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    echo $content;
    ?>
  </div>
```

The iframe code to replace (doesn't work):

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/261467359?app_id=122963" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" title="Mind your Step" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The image code to replace (works):

```
<img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/2018_Ichni_NiakaOngChrapana_4-1024x682.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-15" srcset="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/2018_Ichni_NiakaOngChrapana_4-1024x682.jpg 1024w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/2018_Ichni_NiakaOngChrapana_4-300x200.jpg 300w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/2018_Ichni_NiakaOngChrapana_4-768x512.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" />
```

I've checked the regex using a live regex website and it works; it just does not work when implemented into the wordpress code. The video still appears as per usual. And it is strange that it works perfectly fine to filter out all the images.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show more HTML strings that your code should work on and fails, and some more HTML strings that your code works on and succeeds and tell us the difference.

Comment: Works for me (`<img...` and `<ifram...`), show us more html, the result you get

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the delimiter would work.

```
$content = preg_replace('<iframe[^>]+>.*?<\/iframe>', '', $content);
```

Comment: It worked in python. Can you show us a whole string you are using? It could help us find your problem easily.